# Is there a way to get telnet session output as part of postman test scripts?

Tags: node.js, postman, telnet

I want to test the Web API of a system which has also a CLI accessible via a telnet connection. The tests must verify that the response given to the API requests matches the output of commands given to the CLI.
The problem is that as far as I know there's no way to initiate a telnet connection from inside a postman script.

What will be the best way to achieve this?
Maybe postman is not the best tool for this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What will be the best way to achieve this?

A dedicated script written in NodeJS or any other programming language with or without help of some test framework like Jest \ karma. For sure not Postman.

You can use Postman to run the above mentioned script with `pre-request script` but it just make the all process much more complicated. Almost any modern script language will give you the option to send http request, no need to use postman.

> Maybe postman is not the best tool for this job?

You are right, it's not.